# Convert dd/mm/aaaa 0:00:00 to timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

Im trying to convert with strtotime dd/mm/aaaa 0:00:00 format date to timestamp.

Im using:

```
   $a = "27/01/1981 0:00:00";
   $b = str_replace("/","-",$a);
   echo strtotime($b);
```

But not sure if is the best way
Anyone help?

Thx

Comment: And your problem is that PHP treats `/` separator as US format? Either convert the `/` to a `-`; or use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: recomended Carbon for time related thing in php http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Where is the code you are trying?

Comment: Could you please explain what is `aaaa`? Could you put few examples?

Comment: year, example:  27/01/1981 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

```
php -r "var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('01/02/2016 0:00:00')));"
string(19) "2016-01-02 00:00:00"
```

Just make `strtotime($var);`

Comment: Input format is `dd/mm/aaaa 0:00:00`, not `mm/dd/aaaa 0:00:00`, so this will break dates.... read the question